# How to i program a button to continuously increase or decrease a counter when tapped and on hold?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Button Image**

[image: Screen Shot]

I have defined a RoundIconButton to increase the count when the user taps the button.
If the user needs to increase the count by 50, they have to tap 50 times.

How can i change the button to increase count continuously when the user taps and holds?

```
int age = 20;

RoundIconButton(
 icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
 onPressed: () {
 setState(() {
 age++;
});

class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RoundIconButton({@required this.icon, @required this.onPressed});

  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Icon(icon),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      elevation:
      6.0, // will show only when onpress is defined. it is disabled by default.
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
        width: 56.0,
        height: 56.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you need to use the combination of `Timer` from `dart:async` package with `GestureDetector`. Below is a complete sample of what it would look like based on the sample image your provided.

```
class WeightSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeightSelectState createState() => _WeightSelectState();
}

class _WeightSelectState extends State<WeightSelect> {
  Timer _timer;
  var _weight = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey.shade600,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Weight".toUpperCase(),style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text("$_weight",style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 20,
                            height: 5.0,
                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        if(_weight > 0 ) _weight--;
                      });
                    },
                    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                      print('down');
                      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (t) {
                        setState(() {
                          if(_weight > 0 )
                          _weight--;
                        });
                        print('value $_weight');
                      });
                    },
                    onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                      print('up');
                      _timer.cancel();
                    },
                    onTapCancel: () {
                      print('cancel');
                      _timer.cancel();
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Icon(Icons.add,size: 40.0, color: Colors.white,),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        _weight++;
                      });
                    },
                    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                      print('down');
                      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (t) {
                        setState(() {
                          _weight++;
                        });
                        print('value $_weight');
                      });
                    },
                    onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                      print('up');
                      _timer.cancel();
                    },
                    onTapCancel: () {
                      print('cancel');
                      _timer.cancel();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped. Do accept the answer if this solves your query, it'll be helpful for others.

Comment: if i combine this with a provider (instead of setState) in the timer.periodic, the function calls will keep on firing, even after timer.cancel has been called.
any thoughts?

Comment: i used onLongPress and onLongPressUp instead of onTap by the way

Comment: the onLongPress keep firing if there is a timer.periodic inside it

Comment: Thank you, still works with Flutter: 3.3.1! 
PE: You must adapt to non-nullable expression using Timer? _timer; and   _timer!.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

The [holding_gesture](https://pub.dev/packages/holding_gesture) package allows you to implement the "onHold" gesture:

```
HoldDetector(
  holdTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
  onHold: () {
    x--;
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
)
```

In the above code, while the icon is pressed, the `onHold` callback will be called every 10ms.